# Is the ps1 tag about PowerShell, or is it really about Bash?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

The [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) tag's wiki says:

> Questions about the BASH shell's PS1 input prompt facility.

However, half the questions using the tag are actually about Windows PowerShell, which runs PowerShell scripts with the `.ps1` file extension.

There is already a tag for powershell scripts though: [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell).

Is it time to edit all the PowerShell questions from the [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) tag to the [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag, then edit the [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) tag wiki to clarify that it is not for PowerShell questions?

Comment: A tag about a feature that may or may not be present in some shells... why do we need it?

Comment: @Braiam We don't need a tag about a file extension eiher

Comment: I've been removing the `ps1` tag from PowerShell questions for years. Just added a note to the ps1 tag info page.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto which further my point. There's no need for such a tag, lets just get rid of it and stop ourself from wondering what the heck it should be used for.

Comment: So it's not for PlayStation 1 questions?

Comment: @kjhughes no PlayStation 1 would belong on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I guess my comment needed a :-)

Comment: @kjhughes Apparently it did :-)

Comment: @Braiam It's not obvious to me that the tag should be nuked. I don't know enough about the feature in question to judge, but it seems at least plausible to me that there may be some significant depth of knowledge possible about how Bash prompt customisation works, such that it's sensible to have a tag to group questions about it and bring them to the attention of people with the arcane knowledge required to answer them. Here's a dude with 15 answers in the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1126841+[ps1]; I'd at least try to get him to opine before starting the burnination process.

Comment: @MarkAmery an specific tag for an specific feature which is available on some specific shells or a extension for files meant for a specific program. Why wouldn't be nuked? It's ambiguous as it is used right now and crap at each of their separated usages. Use powershell tag or shell for those. It's unnecessary to have this tag. Oh, btw, did you notice that [all those questions have the bash tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1126841+%5Bps1%5D+-%5Bbash%5D) Or that he has more [answers without ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1126841+ps1+%5Bbash%5D+is%3Aa+-%5Bps1%5D)

Comment: @Braiam I don't think the fact that something is a "feature" is in itself a reason for nuking a tag. Some pieces of software have mere *features* that are more complicated than entire programs or libraries. If such a feature has genuine experts and is complicated enough to inspire a broad array of questions about it, then I have no problem with it having a tag. I'm not saying with confidence that *this particular feature* meets those criteria, because I don't know enough about it to judge, but I *am* saying that "mere features should not have tags" is not a principle I'd want to stand behind.

Comment: @MarkAmery nor it's a reason to have one.

Comment: @Meghan there exists a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps4 tag

Comment: It just isn't a problem, 89% of those questions already either have the [bash] or [powershell] tag.  There are always a few stray ones, including questions that are too lousy for anybody to look at, no real idea how [git] got to be the next common tag.

Comment: @HansPassant probably because people like to modify their prompt to include the git status.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Attempting to force users to not misuse an ambiguous tag is simply bound to fail: we know users tend not to read (tag) descriptions.

I suggest to simply abolish the [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) tag entirely, *and to replace it with two unambiguous tag names*: [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) (already exists) and [shell-prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell-prompt).

Comment: I like `shell-prompt` but I wonder if it's too unspecific - this would also cover `$prompt` from pwsh, `$ps1` from bash and whatever zsh, csh etc use.

Comment: @mikemaccana I think this is a feature: multiple tags can be combined. By contrast, if we have a [tag:bash-prompt] tag, do you also think we should have a [tag:sh-prompt], [tag:ksh-prompt], [tag:fish-prompt], [tag:zsh-prompt], etc?

Comment: Good question. Yes I'd support `ksh-prompt` etc

Comment: No, please no. The feature itself and the extension have proper tags already. [shell] and [powershell]

Answer (score 9):

This a problem of *de jure* vs *de facto*. In practice it means both things, it's ambiguous and a [waste of time of users trying to enforce a meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375047/is-the-ps1-tag-about-powershell-or-is-it-really-about-bash?cb=1#comment636342_375047). I prefer that it means neither and we just remove this from the system. That way we don't have to wonder which meaning it should have and Ansgar can create the next Flappy bird in powershell.

Comment: `bash-prompt` would be a better, more descriptive name.

Comment: @mikemaccana this feature isn't specific to bash.

Comment: I know. But other shells have a different prompt syntax to bash.

Comment: @mikemaccana We don't need a tag representing just bash's shell prompt. The prompt is a commonly understood concept that applies to many different shells. It is enough to have a tag representing that concept and a tag for the particular shell the question is asking about, just as we might have a [tag:for-loop] that can be combined with any number of languages. Sure, the implementation details and syntax and names might differ a little bit, but the basic concept is the same.

Comment: @jpmc Fair enough. I was thinking a question asked about the bash prompt won't be relevant for a csh prompt, a question asked about the pwsh prompt won't be relevant for a ksh prompt. But that logic does also apply to for loops as you say so I've changed my mind here - it's better to be consistent and just have `shell-prompt` or `prompt`

Answer (score 0):

200 questions, 58 [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell), 30 are general shell questions that are likely BASH related (since BASH-like shells are used in other common things with shells, like Git)

I would suggest we rename the tag to [bash-prompt] (since [that's the general concept here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)) and synonym [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) to it. It removes the ambiguity of what it's being used for

Comment: The prompt isn't specific to any shell. There are shells that support prompt customization and others that do not.

Comment: @Braiam Yes it is. pwsh $prompt, bash's $ps1, csh $prompt, and ksh's $ps1 all have different syntax