# Request to burn the [ps1] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) tag is currently being used to describe both [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) (.ps1) questions as well as the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) shell's PS1 input prompt facility, two totally different things.

Back in 2018, the tag excerpt was edited to say:

> DO NOT USE this tag for questions about PowerShell scripts, use [powershell] instead.

but over the months and years, the PowerShell questions have been piling up because users don't read tag excerpts. This results in a tag that is ambiguous and unhelpful.

[Last time the ps1 tag was discussed, general consensus seemed to be that the tag is ambiguous and should just be deleted.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375047/is-the-ps1-tag-about-powershell-or-is-it-really-about-bash)

It's been three years, the tag is still being used in multiple ways, and the list of questions tagged [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) is still a mess. I believe it's time to act on the consensus and burn the [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) tag.

---

The 4 criteria.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tag is definitely ambiguous, and it's clear by now that most users ignore the tag wiki excerpt that attempts to disambiguate it.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Both of the tag's concepts are on-topic for the site.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

For the bash questions it adds a little bit of information, but I am not sure I would call it "meaningful". For the powershell questions, it is a straight up synonym and adds no meaningful information at all.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, there is a relatively even split in the tagged questions between its PowerShell and Bash meanings.

Comment: And for the next episode, a new villain is foreshadowed: the `ps2` tag, which is being used for the bash PS2 input utility, the PS/2 serial HID standard, and Playstation 2 coding.

Comment: Oh, the return of the TLA tags... with a vengeance!

Comment: For a moment, I thought [tag:ps1] was "playstation 1".

Comment: We already have a [tag:command-prompt] tag for questions about shell prompt strings. I agree that [tag:ps1] should be burninated.

Comment: @PCM: [Old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375047/is-the-ps1-tag-about-powershell-or-is-it-really-about-bash#comment636366_375047) joke.  ;-)

Comment: End the game with [ps1]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375167/fixing-the-playstation-tags

Comment: [ps1]: Game Over?

Comment: Yea, but a tag has to fail all four tests to burninate! The second one passes... but burninate anyway!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister And bash has `PS3` and `PS4` special variables too...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This tag calls for disambiguation:

- Retag all PS* questions about bash and add [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) to those that don't have it.
- Retag all PlayStation 1 to use the [playstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playstation)
- Retag all powershell question to use [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)
- Remove the tag from the rest of the questions as it doesn't refer to either bash, powershell or playstation

Comment: [`[bash] [ps1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash+ps1) - 148 questions.  [`[bash] [command-prompt]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash+command-prompt) - 131 questions.  [`[bash][command-prompt] -[ps1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash+command-prompt+-ps1) - 118 questions.  So that's 266 questions about bash command prompts.  That enough demand to retag [tag:ps1] to be [tag:bash] and [tag:command-prompt]?

Comment: Wait, if PlayStation 1 is on-topic on SO, what about Playstation 2,3,4 Those tags should also be retagged right?

Comment: @dbc considering that most questions that use [command-prompt] also use windows, batch and cmd, I doubt that is a viable strategy. In fact, [python] is more popular than those tags. So, no, I don't think [command-prompt] is an alternative. I also question the existence of it.

Comment: @PCM of course, but that's a new Q&A sadly.

Answer (score 5):

How about renaming to `unix-ps1` (after a corrective retag)?

This should make "powershell" users think twice about abusing it.

Comment: PS1 isn't a "concept", PS1 is just the name that has the prompt shown before every command. There's PS0-4, all of those are "prompt string", and no, they doesn't deserve a tag either.

Comment: @Braiam PS1 is also a file type/extension.

Comment: @TylerH I know that (check my answer below), there was a comment saying that PS1 is a bash concept. It isn't. Is just the name that the variable happens to have.

Comment: Both bash (Bourne Again Shell) and Powershell are shells - so this doesn't disambiguate it anyway.

Comment: @user3486184: right, adjusted, thanks, please edit if you have a better suggestion

Comment: Shells run on every OS imaginable. No amount of renaming would make this a good tag.

Comment: So PS1 is not posix/unix specific @braiam ?

Comment: No. As I said in my [first comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411601/request-to-burn-the-ps1-tag/411624?noredirect=1#comment868660_411624), shell prompts are basically universal. PS1 just happens to be the name that bash selected for personalizing theirs.

Comment: exactly, and is the name PS1 used outside of the unix world for this ? (its usage actually predates bash)

Comment: Depends on the shell. Again, no amount of renaming save this one. There's no need to add another tag other than the shell, since that's what is important.

Answer (score -3):

The tag should be disambiguated -- replaced with more specific tags in all questions containing it (after which it'll be automatically deleted after a day).

- In questions about Powershell: [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) -> [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)
- In questions about prompts in other shells: [ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps1) + <shell> -> <shell> + [prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prompt)

Comment: @PCM I'm suggesting a retag

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by the string after "In questions about prompts in other shells."

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister replace one tag combination with another. "&lt;shell&gt;" is intended as a placeholder shell tag but SO apparently doesn't recognize the tag syntax if there are HTML special symbols inside.